# Why does the ASP.NET MVC app loads scripts infinitly?

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, bundles

I've just faced an interestring issue. So, what I have:

1. ASP.NET MVC app;
2. AngularJS app inside this app.

Well, I have a layout page:

```
@using System.Web.Optimization


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>LinkShortener</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/bundles/css/")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/app/libs/")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/app/webapp/")
</head>
<body ng-app="app"></body>
```

Next, there is my Bundle.Config:

```
public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
        {
            bundles.IgnoreList.Clear();

            bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/bundles/css/").Include
                (
                    "~/Content/Css/Bootstrap/*.css"
                ));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/app/libs/")
                .Include("~/App/Libraries/jQuery/jquery-1.9.1.js")
                .Include("~/App/Libraries/Bootstrap/bootstrap.js")
                .Include("~/App/Libraries/Core/angular.js")
                .Include("~/App/Libraries/Core/*.js"));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/app/webapp/")
                .Include("~/App/App.js")
                .Include("~/App/Resources/*Module.js").Include("~/App/Resources/*.js")
                .Include("~/App/Controllers/LinkShortenModule.js").Include("~/App/Controllers/*Controller.js"));

        }
```

When I open my page in Google Chrome, I see something like this:

[script loading loop, the image goes here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vd0xE.png)

It seems any script is beging loaded with the some parameter and then again and again and again...
It it the first time I see this problem. The page is locked by this loop and finally dies.

Is there anyone who could guess what the magic is going on?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try to remove this line

.Include("~/App/Libraries/Core/angular.js")

Comment: You have `"~/App/Libraries/Core/angular.js"` and `"~/App/Libraries/Core/*.js"`. Those are duplicates. So it will load angular.js twice. I'm also guessing `"~/App/Resources/*.js"` has more angular scripts in it. `"~/App/Resources/*.js"` and `"~/App/Resources/*Module.js"` will pick up duplicates too.

Comment: @Vitalii, it solves the issue. But what's the trick?

Comment: DerekMT12 says right. You just have duplicates :) 
Have a nice day :)

Comment: The number at the end is a cache-busting value so the browser always picks up the latest version when the bundle changes.

Comment: @DerekMT12, just updated my bundles to load every script manually (by name), it works fine, but this script crushes all down :  `//.Include("~/App/Libraries/Core/angular-resource.js")`

Answer (score 0):

Did you add `@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)` at end of them?